# showing one viewController from another viewController, when both are part of a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` that contains a `UINavigationController` each as TabbarItems.
Each `UINavigationController` has it's own `UIViewController` as the `rootViewController`.

Now, one of the `rootViewController`s processes some information and sends it to another `rootViewController`.
Then, this `rootViewController` further processes that info and displays it on it's UI.

Till now, i have done this:

```
//from the current VC, taken the reference of the viewController
//to which i have to pass the data.
UINavigationController *controller = (UINavigationController *)self.parentViewController;
UITabBarController *cont = (UITabBarController *)controller.parentViewController;

//called the method of the target viewController that will do further processing
//(to which i will pass the data).
CustomerCareViewController *customerCare = (CustomerCareViewController *)[[cont viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
[customerCare setSRNumber:SRNum];
```

Now, I need to display the processed info (that will be shown on the UI of the target controller)

Comment: So you want to switch from one tab to the other?

Comment: basically yes.. and then i need a back button there that will take the user back to the previous tab, with all old details showing.

Comment: Use the method I posted in my answer then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to switch from one tab to the other, use

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = newIndex;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
[objAppDel.tabBarController setSelectedViewController:[[objAppDel.tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1]];
```

hope this will help you.